# Retaining the AnimationDuration property of the Shield UI ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I have the following problem with my Shield UI ASP.NET Chart. I am setting the duration of its animation to let’s say 7500. I use the property:
AnimationDuration="7500"

and it is to be seen in my code:

```
<shield:ShieldChart ID="ShieldChart2" runat="server" Width="463px" Height="331px"
                OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart2_TakeDataSource" 
    CssClass="chart" AnimationDuration="7500">
```

However when I recreate the chart within my code the animation is quite faster- I assume it is the default one. Here is some of my code:

```
    function PointSelect(args) {
        document.getElementById("QTR").value = args.point.x;
        var detailData = performanceData[args.point.x].values,
        detailChartElement = $('#' + "<%=ShieldChart2.ClientID%>"),
        detailChart = detailChartElement.swidget(),
        initialOptions = detailChart.initialOptions,
        headerText = args.point.name + ' Sales by product';
        detailChart.destroy();
        detailChartElement.shieldChart($.extend(initialOptions, {
            Visible:true,
            primaryHeader: {
                text: headerText
            },
            slicedOffset: 0,
            dataSeries: [
            {
                seriesType: 'pie',
                addToLegend: true,
                enablePointSelection: true,
                collectionAlias: 'Q Data',
                data: detailData
            }
            ],
        }));
```

actually what initializes the chart…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your code, you are recreating the chart, which means, that initial settings are not taken into account. Therefore you need to use the seriesSettings property and set its value accordingly:

```
seriesSettings: {
   pie: {
       applyAnimation: {
           duration: 7500           
       }
   }
}
```